# Check if an undirected graph is a tree in networkx

Tags: python, graph, tree, networkx

I would like to know if there is a simple way to check whether a certain undirected graph in networkx is a tree or not

Comment: I don't know if there's an elegant way to do it with `networkx`, but a simple depth-first traversal, marking the nodes you've visited will work (if it finds an already visited node, there is a cycle and so it's not a tree).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest way for a graph G(V,E) might be to check if |V| = |E| + 1 and  that G is connected:

```
import networkx as nx
def is_tree(G):
    if nx.number_of_nodes(G) != nx.number_of_edges(G) + 1:
        return False
    return nx.is_connected(G)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(is_tree(nx.path_graph(5)))
    print(is_tree(nx.star_graph(5)))
    print(is_tree(nx.house_graph()))
```

Answer (score 7):

There are built-in functions in `networkx` to check the type of a given graph.

To check if it's a tree, run `networkx.is_tree(g)`. See [algorithms for trees in `networkx` documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/tree.html?highlight=tree).

Comment: This is a really old question, and actually at the time this function was not there. More than that, I know because I implemented it myself ;)
It's good to have it as a reference though.